# Representar o eixo x do histograma como as classes da distribuição de frequência?

Tags: r, plot

Estou tendo problemas quando vou fazer um histograma dessa distribuição de frequência.

> Class limits   f   rf rf(%)   cf  cf(%)
>
> [22.691,25.57)  17 0.01  1.29   17   1.29
>
> [25.57,28.45)  25 0.02  1.90   42   3.19
>
> [28.45,31.33)  64 0.05  4.86  106   8.05
>
> [31.33,34.209) 119 0.09  9.04  225  17.08
>
> [34.209,37.089) 169 0.13 12.83  394  29.92
>
> [37.089,39.969) 219 0.17 16.63  613  46.55
>
> [39.969,42.848) 271 0.21 20.58  884  67.12
>
> [42.848,45.728) 185 0.14 14.05 1069  81.17
>
> [45.728,48.608) 139 0.11 10.55 1208  91.72
>
> [48.608,51.487)  72 0.05  5.47 1280  97.19
>
> [51.487,54.367)  29 0.02  2.20 1309  99.39
>
> [54.367,57.247)   8 0.01  0.61 1317 100.00

Basicamente eu queria que no histograma o xlim fosse representado pelas classes da distribuição. Como na imagem:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não pude usar seus dados mas aqui vai um exemplo:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(200, 10)

hist(x)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Defina o limite desejado:

```
lim <- seq(from = 6.7, to = 13.7, by = 1)
> lim
> [1]  6.8  7.8  8.8  9.8 10.8 11.8 12.8
```

Faça o histograma usando o comando `xaxt = 'n'` para plotar sem o axis x, e então use `axis()` para adicionar os valores correspondentes com o limite desejado:

```
hist(x, breaks = lim, xaxt = 'n')
axis(1, at = lim)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!